# MoQ + SetUp via conventions

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Is it possible to setup an mock object's expectations via a mode of conventions and example?

I.e.

```
class Foo
{
     public virtual int? Abc { get; set; } // <-- Convention: Ignore nullable if null 
     public virtual string Xyz { get; set; } // <-- Convention: Ignore null
     public virtual int Dingdong { get; set; } // <-- Convention: Ignore if greater than 10
}
```

Is there an alternative to this or does one have to modify the source to achieve this? Alternatively is there a library that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

You could define a set of conventions in your `AssemblyInitialize` using `It.Is(..)` expressions, and use them during your test setup.

It would also be easy to define some helper methods around it. For example, you could mirror the `It.IsAny<T>()` syntax with an `ItExt.IsConventional<T>()` method. Here's a possible implementation:

```
public static class ItExt
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, object> RegisteredConventions = new Dictionary<Type, object>();

    public static void RegisterConvention<T>(Func<T> convention)
    {
        RegisteredConventions.Add(typeof(T), convention);
    }

    public static T IsConventional<T>()
    {
        Func<T> conventionFunc = (Func<T>)RegisteredConventions[typeof(T)];
        return conventionFunc();
    }
}
```

And usage:

```
[TestClass]
public class FooTests
{
    [AssemblyInitialize]
    public static void AssemblyInitialize(TestContext context)
    {
        ItExt.RegisterConvention(() => It.Is<int?>(n => n.HasValue));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void FooTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        Mock<IFoo> fooMock = new Mock<IFoo>();
        fooMock.Setup(f => f.Bar(ItExt.IsConventional<int?>()))
               .Verifiable();

        // Act
        fooMock.Object.Bar(1);

        // Assert
        fooMock.VerifyAll(); // throws
    }
}
```

Note that convention definitions must be stored as a `Func<T>`, so that the expression in available for evaluation inside the `Mock<T>.Setup` call.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Moq and I am not aware of any library that can do it.